# Derivative of functions of bounded variation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ be a function of bounded variation,in the sense that
\begin{eqnarray}
\sup\limits_{\phi \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}) \\ |\phi|_{L^{\infty}} \leq 1 }\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f\phi_x < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}

Since $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}),$ the distributional derivative of $f$ denoted by $f'$ is a signed radon measure.
How to prove that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} |f'|dx < \infty?$

Comment: This does not make sense: $\int |f'| \le +\infty$ is trivially true. Do you want to ask why the measure $f'$ has finite total variation?

Comment: @daw sorry for the typo... it is a strict inequality...

Comment: Call $d\mu=f'$ in the distributional sense, then by definition $\int \phi \, d\mu = -\int f \phi_x\, dx$, and so $\sup_{\| \phi\|_\infty\leq 1} \left|\int \phi \, d\mu\right|<\infty$. You can extend this to include all $\phi$ bounded Borel functions, and so take $\phi$ the indicator functions of the positive and negative portions of $\mu$.